# Polygon to Polygon: new geometry, preserve attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, polygon

I have two sets of polygon cadastre parcel data with different attributes and slightly varying geometry. What I need to do is to transfer the attributes of Feature A (older) to the geometry of Feature B (newer). This will allow me to compare old attribute data against the updated cadastre. At first glance, this does not seem too complicated. However, A and B do not share the same unique identifier, and the lookup table provided with the datasets is incredibly unreliable. Therefore, I need to complete the attribute transfer through a spatial relationship. The process needs to be as automated as possible due to the size of the datasets.

The problem is further complicated in that not every parcel in Feature A will have a 1:1 relationship with a parcel in Feature B. However, I will focus on reconciling those parcels which do have a 1:1 relationship for now.

My first attempt in ArcGIS included using the Attribute Transfer Tool in the Spatial Adjustment toolbar. The steps I took something like this:

- Use Feature to Line to convert Feature A and B from polygons to lines. This step is necessary because the Attribute Transfer tool only accepts lines as input.
- Run Attribute Transfer Tool with A as the 'Source' feature and B as the 'Target' to transfer attributes of Feature A to the geometry of Feature B. Result: lines in Feature B (within a specified tolerance of lines in A) A now have the attributes of A.
- Run Feature To Polygon to convert these B’s newly attributed lines back to polygons. However, the Feature to Polygon tool has a known bug – so attributes do not transfer to the new polygons although the geometry is created successfully.

So basically I need to find a way to preserve attribution when creating a polygon from attributed lines.

Other strategies I have attempted:

- Workaround using Spatial Join to join the lines of feature A to the polygons of B to the target geometry. However, the results were unreliable and did not produce the expected numbers of matched and unmatched features.
- I have also been fiddling with the “Production Feature Builder” but I have not found a way to use this tool in an automated fashion yet. I have over 16 000 polygons to transfer in total from A to B so a manual update is out of the question!

I'm also open to suggestion in FME, and will post details on what I've already tried there if requested

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  As a new user, please take the 2-minute [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) which explains how things work. This is a pretty complex question, which doesn't fit well with the "Focused question/Best Answer" model used here.  We're better structured to help with one issue than a list of them (details of **exactly** what was attempted will be necessary).

Comment: If you are "still stuck on part 1" then that is what you should focus your question on.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you will be able to use to revise it to contain just the details pertinent to that focussed question.

Comment: @RichardFairhurst I only came across this by chance because you did not use an "@" to ping me. I'm not sure what you mean by "killed" but if you have an answer you want to post just ping me and I'll be very happy to re-open it so that you can do so.

Comment: @RichardFairhurst this question has been re-opened.